# Entity with one-to-many relationships does not record foreign key in table

Tags: java, database, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 database in sql server, in both databases i have the same tables 'entities' and 'field' with one-to-many relationships. I want to save record into those tables in both databases, in first database i have foreign key but in second database JPA doesn't make foreign key.

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "entities")
public class Entity{

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")
private List<Field> fieldList;
...
}

@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "fields")
public class Field {

@Id @Column(name = "id")
private String id;
...
}
```

I creaeted 2 entities 'Entity', 'Field', in spring application contex I created 2 pairs of beans:

```
DriverManagerDataSource, LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, JpaTransactionManager
```

Level DAO:

```
public class EntityDao {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "application")
  private EntityManager entityManager;    

  @Transactional("transactionManager")
  public Entity addEntity(Entity entity){
     entityManager.persist(entity);
  }
}

public class PreviousStateEntityDao {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "administration")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Transactional("transactionManagerAdministration")
  public Entity addPreviousStateEntity(Entity entity){
     entityManager.persist(entity);
  }
}
```

So when I try to persist entity, in first database I have foreign key in second I does not have foreign key. My service looks like:

```
public class EntityServiceImpl implements EntityService {

  @Autowired
  EntityDao entityDao;

  @Autowired
  PreviousStateEntityDao previousStateEntityDao;

  public void addEntity(Entity entity) {
      previousStateEntityDao.addPreviousStateEntity(entity);
      entityDao.addEntity(entity);
  }
```

In this case in DB where I keep  previous state (DB 'administration', tables 'entities', 'fields') i will have foreign key but in main DB 'apllication' where i keep entities i don't have foeign key in table 'fields', JPA write there null. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Make sure that your Field class is imported correctly into your Entity class (that this is it that imported and not some other Field class).

Comment: Correctly, in first DB entity was recorded correctly

Comment: Than try to replace and call **entityDao.addEntity** first and **previousStateEntityDao** after and see the result.

Comment: I tried and i had in main DB (through entityDAO) foreign key, in administration DB (through previousStateEntityDao) no

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it's not right to use the same entity object with two DAOs in JPA. You should try to copy the object before to use it in second dao. So copy-constructor is needed. Something like: `Entity entityForAnotherDao = new Entity(entity);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way. In your controller use it in this way.

```
@PostMapping("/entity")
public Entity postEntity(@RequestBody Entity entity) {

    if( entity.getFieldList().size() > 0 )
    {
        entity.getFieldList().stream().forEach( fieldItem -> {
            fieldItem.setEntity( entity );
        } );
    }
    return entity;
}
```